# Pasar el dato seleccionado de un select a su componente padre en vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, formularios, select

¿Cómo podría pasar el value seleccionado de un Select (componente hijo llamado BaseSelect) a su componente padre llamado FormControl?

Componente hijo denominado BaseSelect

```
<template>
<select>
   <option value="1">Value 1</option>
   <option value="2">Value 2</option>
   <option value="3">Value 3</option>
</select>
</template>
```

En el componente padre quiero acceder a Value del componente base-select

```
<base-select id="select1">
</base-select>
```

Al intentar recuperar el value con javascript (porque así lo necesito) del base-select desde el componente padre obviamente lo desconoce, ya que value es una propiedad que está dentro de base-select

```
document.getElementById('select1').value
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, trate de no abrumarlos con todo mi código y lógica, por lo cual puse todo muy simple.

Comment: Cuando dices "Al intentar recuperar el value con javascript (porque así lo necesito)" ¿Por qué lo necesitas así?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ es un poco complejo, pero básicamente es porque esos controles son generados dinámicamente al recorrer un esquema en JSON. Después dichos controles los proceso con el método nativo submit de formularios de javascript, por lo cual si en el control no hay un dato en la propiedad "Value" no lo va a poder obtener, ya que Javascript Vanilla no trabaja con v-model.

Answer (score 0):

Puede usar `$emit`. Se agrega un evento al componente hijo y a su vez ejecuta un evento del componente padre.

**BaseSelect**

```
<v-select
   v-model="value"
   @change="selected(value)"
   :items="items"      
></v-select>

export default {
  data: () => ({
    items: ["uno", "dos", "tres"],
    value: ""
  }),
  methods: {
    selected(value) {
      this.$emit("selected", value);
    }
  }
};
```

**FormControl**

```
<v-main>
       <BaseSelect @selected="selected" /> 
 </v-main>

import BaseSelect from './components/BaseSelect';

components: {
   BaseSelect
}

methods: {
    selected(val){
      console.log(val)//Puede usarla el valor de select como quiera
    }
  }
```

***BaseSelect*:**
Recibe el evento *selected* que será de tipo change aplicado al select, el cual usa la variable *value* para almacenar el item seleccionado. Luego el evento selected la toma para enviarla como parámetro a la función $emit y moverla al componente padre.

***FormControl***:
Registra el componente *baseSelect* y lo usa en el template agregando el método selected que es usado en el componente hijo.

Comment: Gracias, tu solución funciona pero hay un problema. Si yo intento procesar el formulario con FormData de Javascript no encuentra la propiedad "value" de BaseSelect. Mi pregunta ahora sería: Cuando recibo val en el evento selected de FormControl ¿como puedo asociar val ala propiedad value? para que formdata encuentre esa propiedad.

Comment: @HugoMixerBS  ``FormData`` representa los datos del formulario. Entonces, value que es una propiedad del objeto data() esta fuera. En cuanto a "asociar", es poco entendible. Si quiere enviar un objeto FormData del componente hijo al padre, la respuesta además le sirve de ejemplo.

Comment: Si, funciona, si a alguien le sirve hay que configurar el atributo name a los controles, ya que FormData los recorre por "name" y a partir de ello forma el objeto.

Comment: Si la respuesta le fue de ayuda, no olvide marcarla como útil. Saludos!